# Can download jar file using maven+local repo, but not using maven+nexus?

Tags: maven, nexus

I'm trying to integrate nexus into a maven project and having a problem, hoping someone here can help out.

Initially I had my maven `settings.xml` file to use a local repository only:

```
<settings>
  <localRepository>C:\\r</localRepository>
  ...
</settings>
```

This works fine and all dependencies for my project are downloaded into the local repository. I verified this by deleting the directory for the `maven-settings-2.2.1` artifact and running `mvn -U dependency:list` again:

```
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.2.1/maven-settings-2.2.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.2.1/maven-settings-2.2.1.pom (3 KB at 11.3 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.2.1/maven-settings-2.2.1.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.2.1/maven-settings-2.2.1.jar (48 KB at 509.5 KB/sec)
```

It is seen above that the `pom.xml` and `.jar` file for the `maven-settings-2.2.1` artifact have been downloaded.

Next I tried configuring my maven project to point to a nexus repository that I have set up:

```
<settings>
  <localRepository>C:\\r</localRepository>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
  <id>nexus</id>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
  <url>http://<server>:<port>/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
</mirror>
  </mirrors>
  ...
</settings>
```

I deleted the `maven-settings-2.2.1` artifacts from my local repository, and ran `mvn -U dependency:list` again:

```
Downloading:  http://:/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.2.1/maven-settings-2.2.1.pom
Downloaded: http://:/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.2.1/maven-settings-2.2.1.pom (3 KB at 17.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://:/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.2.1/maven-settings-2.2.1.jar

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project : Could not resolve dependencies for project : The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1 in nexus (http://:/nexus/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]
```

This time, nexus can download the `pom.xml` file the `maven-settings-2.2.1` artifact, but cannot download the `.jar` file. I checked on the nexus server and when I browse the remote contents of the 'central' repository I can see the `maven-settings-2.2.1` artifacts (both `pom.xml` and `.jar` file), but in the nexus local storage I see the `pom.xml` file only.

So I looked at the nexus documentation (see http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html) and set up my maven settings with a nexus profile as suggested:

```
<settings>
  ... as before ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

Again I deleted any local copy of `maven-settings-2.2.1` artifact, and ran `mvn -U dependency:list`:

```
Downloading: http://:/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.2.1/maven-settings-2.2.1.pom
Downloaded: http://:/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.2.1/maven-settings-2.2.1.pom
Downloading: http://:/nexus/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.2.1/maven-settings-2.2.1.jar

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project : Could not resolve dependencies for project : The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1 in nexus (http://:/nexus/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]
```

As before, the `pom.xml` was downloaded from nexus, but not the `.jar` file. And as before, when I inspect the local storage on the nexus server, the `pom.xml` file is present, but not the `.jar` file.

As a sanity test, I removed the nexus configuration from my maven `settings.xml`, removed the `maven-settings-2.2.1` artifacts from my local repository, and tried again:

```
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.2.1/maven-settings-2.2.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.2.1/maven-settings-2.2.1.pom
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.2.1/maven-settings-2.2.1.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-settings/2.2.1/maven-settings-2.2.1.jar
```

This time, both the `pom.xml` and `.jar file were downloaded directly.

So I am not sure what I need to do to get around this issue: when using a local repository and get maven to download dependencies directly, I can download both the `pom.xml` and `.jar` files for the `maven-settings-2.2.1` artifact. When I add my nexus server into the mix, only the `pom.xml` is downloaded by nexus.

Is this a nexus server configuration issue, or a maven configuration issue?

Answer (score 1):

First you misunderstood the meaning of Local Repository.

Even you are using Nexus, you are still having a local repository.  Local repository is simply a repository in your own machine to store all artifacts that Maven will use for build.  In case a dependency is required and is not available in local repository, Maven will contact the remote repository to try to get the dependency.  Once it is get, it is put in local repo so that Maven can continue its build process.

One thing you may have misunderstood too: Even you removed the nexus setting, Maven is still going to download from a default remote repository, which is so-called Maven Central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2).

The whole problem , I believe, is simply you are not setting up your Maven correct to make use of the nexus.  From your quoted config :

```
<url>http://<server>:<port>/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
```

to the error message in Maven:

```
[ERROR] ...  Could not find artifact ... in nexus (http://:/nexus/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]
```

The hostname and port of nexus is simply not correctly setup.

Fix that and everything should work

If such problem is because you masked the data, then the problem will be related to your installation of nexus.  Go in the console site of Nexus, and verify if you have correctly setup the proxies, by browsing remote files of the proxies you set up.  Check if you have Maven central as one of the proxies in the 'public' proxy group too

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm deleting artifacts from my local repo so that maven is then forced to obtain those artifacts elsewhere, either directly from Maven Central, or indirectly via my nexus server, depending on configuration. So I think I have understand that concept correctly?

Comment: The "http://:/nexus/..." in the quote above was a cut-n-paste error, it should be "http://,server>:<port>/nexus/...". It works because other artifacts were downloading, just not the maven-settings-2.2.1 jar file.

Comment: it worked because you have previously built and downloaded it in local repo already and because Maven can find them in local repo, it is not going to download it.  Just to be sure... are you actually seeing `<server>:<port>` or you are just masking it? I am expecting you to tell me that is in fact the real host name and port number.  And, have you tried to make sure that your nexus repo actually works? I have mentioned a way to verify

Comment: "<server>" and <port>" are placeholders for the real server name and port that I did not want to identify. The 'public' group on nexus has 'central' in its groups, and 'central' points to http://repo1.maven.org/maven2. I can download other artifacts from the public group (junit, my own third-party uploads, other maven artifacts) but this particular artifact was not fetched.

Comment: Try to open a browser, fetch the jar by inputting the URL.  If it cannot be fetched, then it is possibly the nexus configuration issue.  I do remember both Maven and Nexus keep some information like "which server has previously failed to provide this artifact" and they will skip that server in the future.  Try to see if you can find such information depending on your testing result, do corresponding cleanup and see if it help

Comment: Now it seems to be working, no change to the configuration of maven or nexus. Must have been a glitch in the matrix at the time.